# log4j2 nested variables feature missing

Tags: logging, log4j2, substitution

On the http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html there is a description how to use property substitution. There is also a small section about "default value nesting" (use your browser search function).

Example from that page: "${id:-${userid}}"
If the id is not set, userid will be used.

It seems that this feature is not supported in the log42. It supports only concrete default values: "${path:-/some/concrete/path/for/example}"

Is there any workaround for this? Where can I place a feature request?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a missing feature it was just a bug. Now it is fixed in the coming 2.8 version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1243

Have fun :)